# Get Acces for Cloud Services in Azure with AD

Tags: azure, service, cloud

I am a Student who wants to try some things on Azure. I want to program an application for Azure Cloud Services. My company doenst have an account on azure.
What is the best Approach do accomplish that with Active Directory, to give mit only acces for this Service?

Comment: Hi, @babastyle . Um.. Azure is a cloud service and you need to create an Azure account for a trial... If you want restrict access to one resource on Azure , you can use RBAC to achieve that. Even, you can secure your Web app with Azure Active Directory...

Comment: do i have to create a custom role?

Comment: That depends on your scenario. You can post more details about it.